# What is the best way to measure correlation for discrete outcomes?

Tags: correlation

I have a dataset where I have the variable on the left, and then outcome on the right. The outcome can only be 1 of 3 possibilities. I want to see if the variable on the left has any impact on the outcome.

What is the best way to measure this and chart this?

```
-314.6  Upgrade +1
-434.6  Completion
-189.6  Upgrade +1
-49.4   Disband
-68.2   Upgrade +1
-91.8   Disband
-70.2   Disband
-84 Completion
-101    Upgrade +1
48  Upgrade +1
-40 Upgrade +1
-58.2   Upgrade +1
-197.8  Upgrade +1
-21.8   Upgrade +1
-100.2  Upgrade +1
-61.6   Disband
-65.8   Completion
-58 Upgrade +1
-362.2  Completion
-150    Disband
-285.6  Completion
-36.4   Upgrade +1
-2.4    Completion
-8  Upgrade +1
-170.2  Completion
-164.6  Completion
-233.2  Disband
26  Upgrade +1
-167.8  Completion
-299.6  Disband
-30.6   Disband
-40 Completion
-428.8  Disband
-297.2  Completion
-133.6  Disband
1.6 Completion
-317.2  Upgrade +1
-290.8  Disband
-263.4  Upgrade +1
-56.8   Completion
-51.6   Completion
-112.8  Completion
11.2    Completion
-166    Completion
-54.8   Upgrade +2
-257.6  Disband
-28.6   Upgrade +1
-170.4  Completion
-387.4  Completion
-118.6  Upgrade +2
-387.4  Completion
-260.8  Upgrade +1
-616.8  Upgrade +1
-616.8  Completion
-211.8  Disband
-268.2  Disband
-166.6  Completion
-291.4  Disband
-152    Completion
-132.2  Disband
-408.6  Completion
-283    Upgrade +2
-322    Disband
-184.6  Upgrade +2
-81.8   Upgrade +1
-212.2  Completion
-9.2    Disband
22.6    Upgrade +1
-16.8   Disband
-215.4  Upgrade +1
-276.4  Upgrade +1
-240.2  Upgrade +1
-305    Upgrade +1
-406.2  Completion
-350.2  Disband
-277    Upgrade +1
-359.4  Disband
-253    Disband
13  Upgrade +1
-360.4  Upgrade +1
```

Here is the same data in R format:

```
dataset <- structure(list(Variable = c(-314.6, -434.6, -189.6, -49.4, -68.2, 
-91.8, -70.2, -84, -101, 48, -40, -58.2, -197.8, -21.8, -100.2, 
-61.6, -65.8, -58, -362.2, -150, -285.6, -36.4, -2.4, -8, -170.2, 
-164.6, -233.2, 26, -167.8, -299.6, -30.6, -40, -428.8, -297.2, 
-133.6, 1.6, -317.2, -290.8, -263.4, -56.8, -51.6, -112.8, 11.2, 
-166, -54.8, -257.6, -28.6, -170.4, -387.4, -118.6, -387.4, -260.8, 
-616.8, -616.8, -211.8, -268.2, -166.6, -291.4, -152, -132.2, 
-408.6, -283, -322, -184.6, -81.8, -212.2, -9.2, 22.6, -16.8, 
-215.4, -276.4, -240.2, -305, -406.2, -350.2, -277, -359.4, -253, 
13, -360.4), Outcome = structure(c(3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Disband", "Completion", 
"Upgrade"), class = c("ordered", "factor"))), row.names = c(NA, 
-80L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Is your outcome nominal or ordinal?

Comment: Nominal means categories like dog/cat/horse pictures. Ordinal means something low/medium/high where there is an order to the categories, even if the distance between the categories is not comparable the way that numbers are. (Note that numbers can be ordinal, such as rating a product 1-5 stars. Is the difference between 2 stars and 3 stars the same as the difference between 4 stars and 5 stars? Probably not, so this is ordinal.)

Comment: Ordinal, Upgrade > Completion > Disband

Comment: No difference between "Upgrade +1" and "Upgrade +2"?

Comment: Yes theres not enough data to separate those outcomes for now. So lets treat those as the same outcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a plot, I would simply plot the `Variable` against the `Outcome`, with a little jitter in the `Outcome` dimension to reduce overfitting. Optionally, add a beanplot or a boxplot (but your dataset is so small that you should really plot the raw data, not only summaries):

[image: plot]

R code:

```
library(beanplot)
with(dataset,
    beanplot(Variable~Outcome,what=c(0,1,0,0),col="lightgray",las=1,xlab="Outcome",ylab="Variable"))
with(dataset,boxplot(Variable~Outcome,add=TRUE,outline=FALSE,xaxt="n",yaxt="n",col=NULL))   
# outline=FALSE because we plot points anyway
set.seed(1) # for replicability
with(dataset,points(as.numeric(Outcome)+runif(nrow(dataset),-.2,.2),Variable,pch=19,cex=0.8))
```

Note how R automatically puts everything in the correct order because we defined `Outcome` as an `ordered` variable.

Now, this does not suggest a strong relationship. (Also, any fitted relationship may be driven by the two points around -600, so it would be good to make an effort to understand where precisely these come from.)

One analytical approach would be an ANOVA of `Variable` against `Outcome`, which suggests that `Variable` on average does not differ between `Outcome`s, $p=.39$:

```
> anova(lm(Variable~Outcome,dataset))
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: Variable
          Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Outcome    2   42106   21053  0.9648 0.3856
Residuals 77 1680186   21821
```

However, this does not account for the *ordered* nature of your `Outcome`. A simple alternative would be to calculate a rank correlation between your `Variable` and the `Outcome`. (A *rank* correlation, because the `Outcome` is [only ordinal, not interval scaled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_measurement).)

```
> cor.test(dataset$Variable,as.numeric(dataset$Outcome),method="kendall")

        Kendall's rank correlation tau

data:  dataset$Variable and as.numeric(dataset$Outcome)
z = 1.2954, p-value = 0.1952
alternative hypothesis: true tau is not equal to 0
sample estimates:
      tau 
0.1131906
```

Finally, you might want to look into ordinal regression or similar methods, but those get more complicated. And to be honest, it does not look like there is a lot there.

---

Edit: [you note](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/507745/what-is-the-best-way-to-measure-correlation-for-discrete-outcomes/507807?noredirect=1#comment938004_507807) that there is a trend in the "average line". Note that the thicker horizontal line in a boxplot is the *median*, not the mean. And yes, the medians increase across the groups:

```
> with(dataset,by(Variable,Outcome,median))
Outcome: Disband
[1] -222.5
-----------------------------------------    
Outcome: Completion
[1] -167.2
-----------------------------------------    
Outcome: Upgrade
[1] -109.8
```

However:

1. While the correlation test using Kendall's $\tau$ above is not strictly speaking a test on medians, as a rank test it is related, and it didn't find anything that would not be consistent with random noise. You could of course run a standard test on medians. (I don't know of one offhand, but you could always ask here on CV, ideally linking to this thread so people can get the context.)
2. And somewhat more importantly, this monotone relationship does not hold for group *means*:

```
> with(dataset,by(Variable,Outcome,mean))
Outcome: Disband
[1] -195.9727
-----------------------------------------    
Outcome: Completion
[1] -206.0154
-----------------------------------------    
Outcome: Upgrade
[1] -155.2562
```

Comment: I guess it definitely is not a strong relationship but there is a clear trend of the "average line" from left to right. Could that be considered at least a medium relationship?

Comment: I addressed your comment in an edit at the bottom, please take a look!